# Event when foreach finished and all promises inside are resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

So I have a `forEach` with `Promises.all` block and then inside the callback for this 2 promises `productsController.addSizeQuantity` and `productsController.addProductsQuantity` I have `productsController.disableProduct` or `productsController.enableProduct` or others (depends on conditions).

What I need to achieve is run some code after `foreach` will be finished and all promises like `productsController.disableProduct` or others will be resolved.

Is there any way to do that?

```js
data.forEach(function (element) {
    var rowArray = element.split(';');

    var torgsoftID = rowArray[0];
    var quantity = rowArray[12];

    Promise.all(
        [
            productsController.addSizeQuantity(torgsoftID, quantity),
            productsController.addProductsQuantity(torgsoftID, quantity)
        ]).then(() => {
        // Disable or enable product/size based on torgsoft information
        productsController.getProductByTorgsoftID(torgsoftID)
            .then(result => {
                if (result.length) {
                    var isEnabled = result[0].enabled;

                    if (!!isEnabled && quantity < 1) {
                        productsController.disableProduct(torgsoftID);
                    } else {
                        productsController.enableProduct(torgsoftID);
                    }
                } else {
                    productsController.getSizeByTorgsoftID(torgsoftID)
                        .then(result => {
                            if (result.length) {
                                if (quantity < 1) {
                                    productsController.disableSize(torgsoftID);
                                } else {
                                    productsController.enableSize(torgsoftID);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                }
            })
    });
})
```

Comment: Don't use `forEach`. Use `map` to create an array of promises and use `Promise.all` again.

Comment: @Bergi Looks like a good solution. Thanks.